# Laravel - update rows in table from array and count updated rows?

Tags: mysql, laravel

What is the best way to solve problem like this:

I have current state of my database with some records. I have an array of objects and i want to update rows in database with array items. When there is object with new ID, which is not in database, i dont want to add this item. At last, i want to count my updated rows.

I've tried something like this:

```
foreach ($providers as $provider) {

        $dbProvider = Provider::where('id', $provider['id'])->first();
        $dbProvider->id = $provider['id'];
        $dbProvider->fill($provider);

        if ($dbProvider->isDirty()) {
            $newlyFoundCount++;
        }

        $dbProvider->save();
    }
```

Is there any way i can achieve this without having to put query inside for loop?

Comment: Hi @Đorđe Sević, May I know if $provider (which represents to updated object/row) have the same set of values?
i.e. every row updating the same columns with same respecting values.

If Yes! then you can avoid loop/foreach. Else you need that loop to update multiple rows for different columns with different values.

Comment: Well, every provider has same attributes but different values.

Comment: how my columns/attribute updated in every provider? if its 1 or 2 then you can make a single query (though it would be complex). 
Else it is better to do that in a loop.